# TypeError: load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. tensorflowjs convertor error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am getting the following error when trying to convert a tensor flow python saved model

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model ./saved_1 ./exported_model
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/a/workspace/pen3/myenv/bin/tensorflowjs_converter", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())

File "/Users/a/workspace/pen3/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 358, in main
strip_debug_ops=FLAGS.strip_debug_ops)

File "/Users/a/workspace/pen3//myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 268, in convert_tf_saved_model
model = load(saved_model_dir, saved_model_tags)

TypeError: load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

these are the contents of saved_1 directory

- saved_model.pb
- variables

  - variables.data-00000-of-00001
  - variables.index

> TensorFlow.js version : 1.13.1
>
> tensorflowjs convertor version : 1.0.1
>
> virtual env with python version: 3.5.5

code in python to save model data. simple linear regression in tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import os
import shutil
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

n_epochs = 11
learning_rate = 0.01

saved_models = 'saved_models'
if os.path.exists(saved_models):
    shutil.rmtree(saved_models)

os.makedirs(saved_models)



housing = fetch_california_housing()
(m,n) = housing.data.shape
scaler = StandardScaler()

scaled_housing_data = scaler.fit_transform(housing.data)
scaled_housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), scaled_housing_data]

X = tf.constant( scaled_housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32 , name='X')
Y = tf.constant( housing.target.reshape(-1, 1) , dtype=tf.float32, name='Y')
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform( [n+1, 1] , -1.0, 1.0))

y_pred = tf.matmul( X, theta, name='predictions')
error = y_pred - Y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")
gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), error)
training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
            tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, saved_models + '/model_' + str(epoch) , inputs={'myInput' :X },  outputs={'myOutput' : y_pred })
        sess.run(training_op)


    best_theta = theta.eval()

print(best_theta)
```

Comment: Could you please show your python code ?

Comment: i have just added one line:   tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'saved_1', inputs={'myInput' :x },  outputs={'myOutput' :y })

Comment: If possible could you add the whole python code that is converted ?

Comment: @edkeveked added the code. i am unable to get tensorflow js convertor to work for "saved model" format.

Comment: it seems that tfjs-converter 1.0.1 requires tensorflow > 2.0.0. Maybe you can either upgrade tensorflow or downgrade tensorflowjs-converter